# Stack Smashing in C

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I wanted to detect stack smashing occurrence in a C program by parsing it.
I wanted to do this in Java.

Can any one lead me to start with it.

How to detect presence of stack smashing in a C program.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't feasible, in general. In fact, it looks like an expression of the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Stack smashing detection is performed at run-time. You might start by looking at the article on [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection), and the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stack%20smashing) questions and answers already provided on stackoverflow.

Comment: Keeping " Stack smashing detection" or just "stack smashing " as the subject we need to come up with a project. Can you suggest any thing that can be developed. we have 2 weeks. I just need an idea to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with writing a program to make stack smashing.
One example from my own experience is the following code.

```
int main(void)
{
    char hello[] = "hello";
    printf("%s\n",strcat(hello, "world"));
}
```

This can give you the stack smashing detection warning with segmentation fault

You can also correct this by inserting the size for the string big enough to hold the appended string. 
i.e.,

```
int main(void)
{
    char hello[50] = "hello";
    printf("%s\n",strcat(hello, "world"));
}
```